# problem installin vala 0.15.0 Gobobject not found

Tags: vala

```
/gir/bug651773: FAIL
error: Package `GLib-2.0' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories
error: Package `GObject-2.0' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories
Generation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
1 of 145 tests failed
make[4]: *** [check-TESTS] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/suman/Downloads/vala-0.15.0/tests'
make[3]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/suman/Downloads/vala-0.15.0/tests'
make[2]: *** [check] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/suman/Downloads/vala-0.15.0/tests'
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/suman/Downloads/vala-0.15.0'
make: *** [check] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

0.15.0 isn't just old, it's an unstable development release.  There is no reason for anyone to be using it.  0.22.0 is out, and there aren't any dependencies on newer software which should cause problems (IIRC our only real dependency is on glib >= 2.18 and I don't think that is any different than vala-0.15), so you should probably be using it.

If, for some reason, you need an older version of Vala then you should use a stable release.  If you can't build it post a complete log.  Also, running the unit tests aren't a requirement for installation.  If the problem only manifests itself when trying to run the unit tests, don't run them.  Nobody is going to bother backporting fixes to 0.15 or 0.16, so there isn't really much of a point.

Comment: it didn't help.check the link for the log [link](http://pastebin.com/8Bi4PART)

Comment: Do you have the GIRs for GLib-2.0 and GObject-2.0 installed (the libgirepository1.0-dev package in Ubuntu)?